# How to SCP a file from a 2-deep connection

Tags: scp

Say I SSH into a server `Server1` and from there SSH into server `Server2` which is only accessible from a connection to `Server1`.  Below simulates the example terminal commands for this behaviour:

```
[name@mylaptop]$ ssh user@Server1
user@Server1's password:
*** Welcome to Server1! ***
[user@Server1]$ ssh user2@Server2
user2@Server2's password:
*** Welcome to Server2! ***
[user2@Server2]$
```

Now I have a file, named `file.txt` in my home directory on `Server2`:

```
[user2@Server2]$ ls
file.txt
[user2@Server2]$
```

Is it possible to use `scp` to copy `file.txt` from `Server2` onto `mylaptop` with a single command (i.e. not needing to first copy the file to `Server1`)?

In other words, can this be done easier than the following:

```
[name@mylaptop]$ ssh user@Server1
user@Server1's password:
*** Welcome to Server1! ***
[user@Server1]$ scp user2@Server2:~/file.txt .
user2@Server2's password:
file.txt                                            100%  690     0.7KB/s   00:00
[user@Server1]$ logout
Connection to Server1 closed.
[name@mylaptop]$ scp user1@Server1:~/file.txt .
user@Server1's password:
file.txt                                            100%  690     0.7KB/s   00:00
[name@mylaptop]$ ls
file.txt
```

Comment: Is the Client->Server2 restriction due to 1. Server2 cannot be reached because a firewall blocks the traffic or 2. Can't log into Server2 becuase the required credentials are only on Server1?

Comment: @DarkFalcon I'm not sure what you mean by #2 (the login credentials for Server2 should be on Server2), but the only connection from Server2 to anything is by means of Server1.  I.e Server2 is connected directly into Server1 via ethernet and is not connected by any other means.  All traffic to Server2 is forwarded through Server1.  Hope this clears things up.

Comment: What I meant by credentials is that is is possible to login over ssh automatically via a public/private key pair. If you were doing this, you could wish that the private key for Server2 only reside on Server1 and never be coped to your Client machine.

Comment: @DarkFalcon thank you for the clarification.  I am honestly not sure if this is true/possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the answers on ServerFault :
https://serverfault.com/questions/37629/how-do-i-do-multihop-scp-transfers.

The answers cover a variety of flavours of ssh.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible and relatively easy, even when you need to use certificates for authentication (typical in AWS environments).

The command below will copy files from a `remotePath` on `server2` directly into your machine at `localPath`. Internally the scp request is proxied via `server1`.

```
scp -i user2-cert.pem -o ProxyCommand="ssh -i user1-cert.pem -W %h:%p user1@server1" user2@server2:/<remotePath> <localpath>
```

If you use password authentication instead, try with

```
scp -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p user1@server1" user2@server2:/<remotePath> <localpath>
```

If you use the same user credentials in both servers:

```
scp -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p commonuser@server1" commonuser@server2:/<remotePath> <localpath>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use port forwarding:
Execute

```
ssh  -L60000:Server2:22 user@Server1
```

in one terminal and keep this process open.

Then in another terminal run

```
scp -P 60000 user2@localhost:file.txt .
```

(You can replace 60000 by your favourite port number)